# write then read from data file in cplex

Tags: cplex

I have the below code to write the arrays values in a data file, Then read it's values again in another array from the same data file in the same model, but it gives me an error "Data element Example has been already set" How to slove this. and thanks

```
range Number= 0..6;
int Example [i in Number]=i;
   
  execute
 {
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("Example.dat");
  o.writeln("Example=");
  o.writeln(Example);
  o.writeln(";");
  o.close();
  }
     
main {
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("Write and read from the data file.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
  var data = new IloOplDataSource("Example.dat");
  opl.addDataSource(data);
  opl.generate();
  if (cplex.solve())
   {
     writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());

  }
   else
    {
     writeln("No solution");
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sub.mod

```
subject to
{
  
}

range Number= 0..6;
int Example [i in Number]=i;
   
  execute
 {
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("Example.dat");
  o.writeln("Example=");
  o.writeln(Example);
  o.writeln(";");
  o.close();
  }
```

and sub2.mod

```
range Number= 0..6;
int Example [i in Number]=...;

dvar int obj;   
subject to
{
  obj==sum(i in Number) Example[i];
}

execute
{
  writeln("obj=",obj);
}
```

then the following .mod

```
main {
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
  opl.generate();
  cplex.solve();
  opl.postProcess();
  var source2 = new IloOplModelSource("sub2.mod");
  var def2 = new IloOplModelDefinition(source2);
  var opl2 = new IloOplModel(def2,cplex);
  var data2 = new IloOplDataSource("Example.dat");
  opl2.addDataSource(data2);
  opl2.generate();
  if (cplex.solve())
   {
     writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());

  }
   else
    {
     writeln("No solution");
  }
  opl2.postProcess();
  }
```

gives

```
OBJ = 0
obj=21
```

and with only one .mod

sub.mod

```
range Number= 0..6;

int ExampleIn [i in Number]=...;

dvar int obj;   
subject to
{
  obj==sum(i in Number) ExampleIn[i];
}

execute
{
  writeln("obj=",obj);
}

int ExampleOut [i in Number]=i+obj;
   
  execute
 {
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("Example.dat");
  o.writeln("ExampleIn=");
  o.writeln(ExampleOut);
  o.writeln(";");
  o.close();
  }
```

Example.dat

```
ExampleIn=
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
;
```

then

```
main {
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
  var data= new IloOplDataSource("Example.dat");
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
  opl.addDataSource(data);
  
  opl.generate();
  cplex.solve();
  opl.postProcess();
  var source2 = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var def2 = new IloOplModelDefinition(source2);
  var opl2 = new IloOplModel(def2,cplex);
  var data2 = new IloOplDataSource("Example.dat");
  opl2.addDataSource(data2);
  opl2.generate();
  if (cplex.solve())
   {
     writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());

  }
   else
    {
     writeln("No solution");
  }
  opl2.postProcess();
  }
```

gives

```
obj=0
OBJ = 0
obj=21
```

Comment: Thank you, But i want all of them in one .mod. Thanks